# Limitations to using (Boost) Asio with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, boost-asio

What are the current limitations for using Asio with NDK on Android platforms?
Would there be any other choice that you would definitely choose over Asio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As such no limitation. Only concern is lack of official support.
You would have to build boost libraries refer my post https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/19511559 thanks